# Empty results from concurrent psycopg2 postgres select queries

Tags: python, postgresql, concurrency, pytorch, psycopg2

I am attempting to retrieve my label and feature datasets from a postgres database using the **getitem** method from a custom pytorch dataset. When I attempt to sample with random indexes my queries return no results

I have checked to see if my queries work directly on the psql cli. They do. 
I have checked my database connection pool for issues. Does not seem to be any. 
I have reverted back to sequential sampling and it is still fully functional so it is the random index values that seem to be an issue for query.

The **getitem** method which performs the queries is place below. This shows both the sequential and attempt to shuffle queries. Both of these are clearly labeled via variable name.

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):

        query = """SELECT ls.taxonomic_id, it.tensor
                    FROM genomics.tensors2 AS it
                    INNER JOIN genomics.labeled_sequences AS ls
                    ON ls.accession_number = it.accession_number
                    WHERE (%s) <= it.index 
                    AND CARDINALITY(tensor) = 89
                    LIMIT (%s) OFFSET (%s)"""

        shuffle_query = """BEGIN
                           SELECT ls.taxonomic_id, it.tensor
                           FROM genomics.tensors2 AS it
                           INNER JOIN genomics.labeled_sequences AS ls
                           ON ls.accession_number = it.accession_number
                           WHERE it.index BETWEEN (%s) AND (%s)
                           END"""


        batch_size = 500
        upper_bound = idx + batch_size

        query_data = (idx, batch_size, batch_size)
        shuffle_query_data = (idx, upper_bound)

        result = None
        results = None

        conn = self.conn_pool.getconn() 

        try:
            conn.set_session(readonly=True, autocommit=True)
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query, query_data)
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            self.conn_pool.putconn(conn)


            print(idx)
            print(results)        
        except Error as conn_pool_error:
            print('Multithreaded __getitem__ query error')
            print(conn_pool_error)

        label_list = []
        sequence_list = []

        for (i,result) in enumerate(results):
            if result is not None:
                (label, sequence) = self.create_batch_stack_element(result)

                label_list.append(label)
                sequence_list.append(sequence)

        label_stack = torch.stack(label_list).to('cuda')
        sequence_stack = torch.stack(sequence_list).to('cuda')

        return (label_stack, sequence_stack)


    def create_batch_stack_element(self, result):
        if result is not None:

            label = np.array(result[0], dtype=np.int64)
            sequence = np.array(result[1], dtype=np.int64)

            label = torch.from_numpy(label)
            sequence = torch.from_numpy(sequence)

            return (label, sequence)

        else:
            return None
```

The error I receive comes from my attempt to stack my list of tensors after the for loop. This fails because the lists are empty. Since the lists are filled in the loop based off the results of the query. It points to the query being the issue.

I would like some help with my source code to solve this issue and possibly an explanation as to why my concurrent queries with random indexes are failing.

Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

E: I believe I have found the source of the issue and it comes from the pytorch RandomSampler source code. I believe it is providing indexed out of the range of my database keys. This explains why I have no results from the queries. I will have to write my own sampler class to limit this value to the length of my dataset. What an oversight on my part.

E2: The random sampling now works with a customized sampler class but prevents mutlithreaded querying.

E3: I now have the entire problem solved. Using multiple processes to load data to the GPU with a custom random sampler. Will post applicable code when I get a chance and accept it as an answer to close out the thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is a properly constructed getitem for pytorch from a postgres table with indexable keys.

```
def __getitem__(self, idx: int) -> tuple:

    query = """SELECT ls.taxonomic_id, it.tensor
               FROM genomics.tensors2 AS it
               INNER JOIN genomics.labeled_sequences AS ls
               ON ls.accession_number = it.accession_number
               WHERE (%s) = it.index"""

    query_data = (idx,)

    result = None

    conn = self.conn_pool.getconn()

    try:
        conn.set_session(readonly=True, autocommit=True)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, query_data)
        result = cursor.fetchone()

        self.conn_pool.putconn(conn)
    except Error as conn_pool_error:
        print('Multithreaded __getitem__ query error')
        print(conn_pool_error)

    return result

def collate(self, results: list) -> tuple:

    label_list = []
    sequence_list = []

    for result in results:
        if result is not None:
            print(result)
            result = self.create_batch_stack_element(result)

            if result is not None:
                label_list.append(result[0])
                sequence_list.append(result[1])

    label_stack = torch.stack(label_list)
    sequence_stack = torch.stack(sequence_list)

    return (label_stack, sequence_stack)



def create_batch_stack_element(self, result: tuple) -> tuple:

    if result is not None:

        label = np.array(result[0], dtype=np.int64)
        sequence = np.array(result[1], dtype=np.int64)

        label = torch.from_numpy(label)
        sequence = torch.from_numpy(sequence)

        return (label, sequence)

    return None
```

Then I called my training function with:

```
for rank in range(num_processes):
    p = mp.Process(target=train, args=(dataloader,))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```